# Incomplete output about Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Tags: java, terminal

I want to build an app like Jenkins terminal:
[image: jenkins terminal snapshot]

And I use Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` to execute the command, find out that the output is incomplete.

textshell.sh:

```
# textshell.sh
echo "wwwwwww";
sleep 2
ls
```

For example:
When I execute textshell.sh in my mac terminal`sh -x testshell.sh` , output :

```
+ echo wwwwwww
wwwwwww
+ sleep 2
+ ls
testshell.sh
```

but when I execute by java `Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -x testshell.sh")` , output:

```
wwwwwww
testshell.sh
```

the shell args `-x` seems useless

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems the "+" prefixed lines are printed to stderr instead. Make sure to consume (and display) both the standard output and the standard error streams.

Comment: Try to run this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-x", "testshell.sh"})`

Comment: Read the standard error streams and problem fixed, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joachim Sauer points out you are not reading STDERR so miss the lines of echo output from the `set -x` output. Adjust your code to access the `process.getErrorStream()` as well.

Alternatively you can switch to `ProcessBuilder` if wanting to read the error stream merged with the output:

```
String[]cmd = new String[]{"sh", "-x", "testshell.sh"}
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

// THIS MERGES STDERR>STDOUT:
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

// EITHER send all output to a file here:
Path stdout = Path.of("mergedio.txt");
pb.redirectOutput(stdout.toFile());

Process p = pb.start();

// OR consume your STDOUT p.getInputStream() here as before:

int rc = p.waitFor();

System.out.println("STDOUT: \""+Files.readString(stdout)+'"');
```

Comment: problem fixed, and ``` pb.redirectErrorStream(true); ``` really helpful, thank you!!